# Laravel 5.8: Request session does not seem to setting the session at Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-session

My request session doesn't seem to set the session in the controller. As you can see by saying `$request->session()->flash('charge_wallet',$wallet);`, I tried to set the session `charge_wallet`.

Then in the view, `bankGateWay.getToken`, I tried checking if the session exists or not. But it returns **not exists** somehow! So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

**Controller**

```
public function chargeWallet(Request $request, $wallet, $user)
{
    try {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'charge' => 'required|integer|min:1000',
        ]);

        $payment = Payment::create([
            'pay_type_id' => '191',
            'pay_date' => jdate()->format('Y/m/d'),
            'pay_amount' => $data['charge'] * 10,
            'pay_ord_id' => '',
            'pay_status_id' => '181',
            'pay_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
        ]);

        $request->session()->flash('charge_wallet', $wallet); // Setting Session

        $sendInformation = new BankGateWay($payment->pay_id, 
            $payment->pay_amount, $payment->created_at->timestamp,
            route('returnFromGateCharge'));
        
        return view("bankGateWay.getToken", compact('sendInformation'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Wrong Data');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@if(Session::has('charge_wallet'))
    @dd('exists');
@else
    @dd('not exists');
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function chargeWallet(Request $request, $wallet, $user)
    {
        try {
            $data = $request->validate([
                'charge' => 'required|integer|min:1000',
            ]);

            $payment = Payment::create([
                'pay_type_id' => '191',
                'pay_date' => jdate()->format('Y/m/d'),
                'pay_amount' => $data['charge'] * 10,
                'pay_ord_id' => '',
                'pay_status_id' => '181',
                'pay_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
            ]);

            $sendInformation = new BankGateWay($payment->pay_id, $payment->pay_amount, $payment->created_at->timestamp, route('returnFromGateCharge'));
            return view("bankGateWay.getToken", compact('sendInformation'))->with('charge_wallet',$wallet);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Wrong Data');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually as the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data) tells, you can use it for the next requests, for example after redirecting.

> Data stored in the session using this method will be available
> immediately and during the subsequent HTTP request. After the
> subsequent HTTP request, the flashed data will be deleted.

But in your code you want to show it in your view, which is considered in the same request. For the current request you should use `now` method.

```php
$request->session()->now('charge_wallet',$wallet');
```

If you want to set for a longer time, use `put` method.

```php
$request->session()->put('charge_wallet',$wallet');
```